Programming ELM327 PIC18
I have (second hand) a modified  ELM327 with 18F25K80 and a FT232, seems has been modified to be programable via USB has a jumper wire from pin 3 (reset) from FT to pin 1 (mclr) 18F, swap quartz and a removed component in the corner.
I wanna know if can be programable like this and which program can be used? I think it was programed to accept another value of quartz from the stock 4000.



That's one ugly patch. Has to be redone with thinner cable <AWG30. Use insulated wire, then there's no need of shrinking tubes.

The original firmware v1.0 has been leaked to the internet, but it contains several bugs.
